# how to get URL of media uploaded to WordPress via media_handle_sideload()

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, uploads, media-library, terms

I'm trying to upload a photo from an URL then set it as the feature image of a product that user is submitting

Now I can do the first part of this function
the problem is I can't get the new URL of the media and set it as the feature image for WooCommerce product

here is the code

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'new_product_add', 10, 3);
function new_product_add($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if( 
        $old_status != 'publish' 
        && $new_status == 'pending' 
        && !empty($post->ID) 
        && in_array( $post->post_type, 
            array( 'product') 
            )
        ) {
            $external_url = $post->post_excerpt;
            /********************************************/
            function uploadImageToMediaLibrary($postID, $url, $alt = "blabla") {
                $tmp = download_url( $url );
                $desc = $alt;
                $file_array = array();
                preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpe|jpeg|gif|png)/i', $url, $matches);
                $file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
                $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;
                if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
                    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
                    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
                }
                $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $postID, $desc);
                if ( is_wp_error($id) ) {
                    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
                    return $id;
                }
                return $id;
            }
            uploadImageToMediaLibrary($post->ID, $external_url, "custom_alt");

                //MEDIA UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY
                //I DONT KNOW HOW TO GET THE NEW MEDIA URL FROM MEDIA GALLERY 
                //AND SET IT FOR THE PRODUCT FEATURE IMAGE


                /********************************************/
                $term = get_term_by('name', 'PARENT_CATEGORY', 'product_cat');
                wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, $term->term_id, 'product_cat', true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL of the uploaded image/attachment, you can use [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/) (which *always* returns the full-sized image URL) or [`wp_get_attachment_image_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) for image attachment:

```php
// This is how you should call uploadImageToMediaLibrary(); assign the value to $att_id.
$att_id = uploadImageToMediaLibrary($post->ID, $external_url, "custom_alt");
$url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $att_id, 'full' ); // full-sized URL
```

But to set the image as the *featured image* of the post where the image was uploaded to, or any posts actually, then you would use [`set_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail/) like so:

```php
$att_id = uploadImageToMediaLibrary($post->ID, $external_url, "custom_alt");
if ( ! is_wp_error( $att_id ) && $att_id ) {
  set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $att_id );
}
```

*PS: I revised this answer because using `set_post_thumbnail()` is much preferred than manually updating the private metadata `_thumbnail_id` used for post featured images..* =)